# Not able to use imported type as property type in QML when imported with qualifier

Tags: qml

To e.g. avoid namespace conflicts I want to import a module in QML using a qualifier:

```
import <ModuleIdentifier> <Version.Number> [as <Qualifier>]
```

so in my case I use:

```
import com.myorg.models 1.0 as Model
```

In this import I have a type named "User". I then want to use this as a property with type 'User' in a QML file.

```
//User.qml
import QtQuick 2.8
import com.myorg.model 1.0 as Model

Item {
    property Model.User user         //This does not work
    property var user: Model.User {} //This does work, but if possible I want to avoid 'var'.
    property User user               //This works, if I remove the qualified name in the import statement.
}
```

So without the 'Model' qualifier in the import statement I can use 'User' as a type in the property, but once you use a qualifier you can not. This seems strange to me. Is there any good reason for it or is it just not supported?

Personally I would like to be able to do:

```
property Model.User user
```

just like i can when using no qualifier:

```
property User user
```

Comment: Rather then `var` you might also use `QtObject` which is probably better.

Comment: @derM: That is a good tip. At least it's a bit close to the actual concrete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in Qt. It got fixed in Qt 5.8.0: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10822.